# Class in TR without one TD

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
    <tr class="here"><td><input type="text" readonly=readonly></td></tr>
    <tr class="here"><td><input type="text" readonly=readonly></td></tr>
    <tr class="here"><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
</table>

td {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.here {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dZYEM/

How can i modify class .here that this working where child input has attribute readonly? I dont want modify html.

EDIT:

now i have: jsfiddle.net/dZYEM/2/

i would like receive: http://jsfiddle.net/dZYEM/3/

but without use style. I want receive this only with css.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is very clear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Gaz very unclear you mean, right?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dZYEM/9/ ?

Comment: You can use jquery or javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no pure CSS way to do this as CSS does not have a *has* or *contains* selector.

But this can be done using one line of jQuery. And it's really fast.

`$("tr.here:has(input[readonly='readonly'])").css('background', 'red');`

Here is a working jsFiddle to try it - http://jsfiddle.net/T7hnR/2/

Comment: +1, shorter version $(".here:has([readonly])").css('background', 'red');

Answer (score 1):

Hey you have two option

**first is** if your **tr** is **last** than apply this css

```
tr:last-child{
background:none;
}
```

**Second is** if your **tr number** is **3** than used to it.

```
tr:nth-of-type(3){
background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could edit the inner element by makiung use of [CSS2 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

> E[foo="warning"]  Matches any E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "warning".

But this will not allow you to select the outer parent element.
Under either CSS2 or CSS3 this does not exist, and you would *have* to do it with the solutions provided with JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: thanks, indeed it's not the required result. After some research, it seems not to be able to be done with CSS alone. (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Like here : http://jsfiddle.net/dZYEM/10/

**CSS:**

```
tr:nth-child(3n) {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: this is ok for this example, but these TR is more and this is added with ajax